# Unable to send E2C Message to Azure IoTHub from python

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

I was creating on a simulator which sends simulate edge-to-cloud message from the simulated device to IoT Hub. I ran into some issues while I following the code in official documentation and GitHub pages of the SDK.

Here's my code:

```
async def send_e2c_message(self):
   # ConnectionString get from IoT Hub
   conn_str = "HostName={IoTHubName};SharedAccessKeyName=service;SharedAccessKey={SomeAccessKey}"

   # The client object is used to interact with the Azure IoT hub.
   device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(conn_str)

   # Connect the client.
   await device_client.connect()

   # Send message
   print("Sending message...")
   await device_client.send_message('Hello World')
   print("Message successfully sent!")

   # Disconnect client
   await device_client.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(IoTHubAccessor.send_e2c_message(self))
```

The error shows are as below:

```
Unexpected error in <azure.iot.device.iothub.pipeline.pipeline_stages_iothub.UseAuthProviderStage object at 0x03E31CF0>._execute_op() call
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
  ...
in _execute_op
    sas_token=self.auth_provider.get_current_sas_token(),
  File 
  ...
in get_current_sas_token
    self.generate_new_sas_token()
  File 
resource_uri = self.hostname + "/devices/" + self.device_id
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
UseAuthProviderStage(SetAuthProviderOperation): completing with error can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
Exception caught in background thread.  Unable to handle.

File 
"...\pipeline_stages_mqtt.py", line 37, in _cancel_pending_connection_op
    op = self._pending_connection_op
AttributeError: 'MQTTTransportStage' object has no attribute '_pending_connection_op'
MQTTTransportStage(ConnectOperation): completing with error 'MQTTTransportStage' object has no attribute '_pending_connection_op'
SerializeConnectOpsStage(ConnectOperation): completing with error 'MQTTTransportStage' object has no attribute '_pending_connection_op'
Unhandled exception in background thread
This may cause the background thread to abort and may result in system instability.
```

I get the picture that I have to provide somewhat the DeviceId, however, the DeviceId in the connection string won't work. I have no idea where to put it.

I merely just follow the sample given by official documentation so I do not know what is the problem. If anyone could help I really appreciates it.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post what you connection string looks like? (obfuscate all secrets)

Comment: @silent Yes already updated the question with it!

Comment: btw, I assume you mean "D2C" (device-2-cloud messages), not E2C?!

Comment: @silent The device does call edge-device tho...It's supposed to accept the data from a sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong connection string. Since you want to send messages from the [device-side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints), you need to use a device connection string:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried to access to it, but on that page all I can find is a thing called 'thumbprint'... Is it the same usage as connection string?

Comment: Did you create your device with x509 authentication?!

Comment: The device creation is done by other people. I need to send a simulate message to the Hub to testing the device and the flow. And yes I think they have implemented the x509 authentication.

Comment: Then follow this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/legacy-samples/send_message_x509.py